# Laravel 5. Error: my model with trashed and one relation.

Tags: laravel

Problem exists because transhed added, conflicted with tablerelation.

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function category() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Category', 'id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Post;
use Session;
use Auth;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = new Post();
        // $allPosts = $posts::onlyTrashed()->get();
        // $allPosts = $posts::withTrashed()->get();
        $allPosts = $posts::all();
        $postDeleted = $posts::onlyTrashed()->count();
        return view('admin.post.index', ['posts' => $allPosts, 'postDeleted' => $postDeleted]);
    }
```

...

View:

```
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <tr class="table-pages-list-item">
          <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>{{ $post->h1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ $post->url }}</td>
          <td>{{ $post->category->h1 }}</td>
          <td>
            @if ($post->published)
                        <span class="label label-success">Да</span> 
                    @else
                        <span class="label label-danger">Нет</span>
                    @endif
          </td>
          <td>{{$post->updated_at}}</td>
          <td>
            <a href="#"type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Редактировать">
              <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" target="_blank" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Просмотреть">
              <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>
            </a>
            <form action="{{ action('PostController@destroy', ['id' => $post->id]) }}" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
              <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="В корзину">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
              </button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Error here `<td>{{ $post->category->h1 }}</td>`

Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\OpenServer\domains\laravel\resources\views\admin\post\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

because you are naming your foreign key as `category_id` like the convention,i think you should define eloquent relationship like this

```
public function category() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Category');
}
```

you should see hasOne method on `Model.php` file how to define one to one relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Please check what fields your category table has!
Does it contains 'h1' field, you are accessing 'h1' key, but may be its not there at table